# Weird behavior of Mapcache?

Tags: mapserver, mapcache

I have installed Mapcache 1.6 and Mapserver 7.0.6. I created configuration file (You can see below this text) and I generated tiles throught mapcache_seed. I have tiles in folder but I have problem with it. If I send first request to Mapcache with generated dataset(which was generated by mapcache_seed) Mapcache again execute Mapserver and I feel big delay. It look like regeneration of tiles. If I send same request the second time, I work ok a Mapcache don’t execute Mapserver and I get tiles very fast.

What am I doing wrong ?

Configuration file, which I use it:

```
<cache name="disk" type="disk" >

    <base>/opt/data/share/maps/mapcache/</base>

    <symlink_blank/>

</cache>



<source name="zdroj" type="wms">

    <getmap>

        <params>

         <MAP>/opt/data/share/maps/mapserver/main.map</MAP>

          <FORMAT>image/png</FORMAT>

            <transparent>true</transparent>

            <layers>all</layers>

       </params>

    </getmap>

    <http>

        <url>http://172.17.0.1:8085/mapserver?</url>

    </http>

</source>

<format name="PNG_BEST" type ="PNG">

    <transparent>true</transparent>

</format>

<format name="jpeg_nastaveni" type ="JPEG">

    <quality>95</quality>

    <photometric>RGB</photometric>

</format>



<tileset name="mirror">

    <source>zdroj</source>

    <cache >disk</cache>

    <grid>gridRP</grid>

    <format>PNG_BEST</format>

    <metatile>5 5</metatile>

    <metabuffer>10</metabuffer>

</tileset>



<grid name="gridRP">

    <extent>-20037508.3427892480 -20037508.3427892480 20037508.3427892480 20037508.3427892480</extent>

    <srs>EPSG:3857</srs>

    <units>m</units>

    <size>256 256</size>

    <resolutions>156412 78206 39103 19551 9776 4888 2444 1222 610.984 305.492 152.746 76.373 38.187 19.093 9.547 4.773 2.387 1.193 0.596 0.298</resolutions>

</grid>



<service type="wms" enabled="true">

    <full_wms>error</full_wms>

    <format allow_client_override="true">PNG_BEST</format>

</service>

<service type="wmts" enabled="true"/>

<service type="tms" enabled="true"/>

<service type="kml" enabled="true"/>

<service type="gmaps" enabled="true"/>

<service type="ve" enabled="true"/>



<errors>report</errors>

<lock_dir>/tmp</lock_dir>
```

Comment: What is your seed command?

Comment: I use this: mapcache_seed -c mapcacheRPG.xml -t mirror -z 9,15 -n 2